# Single MSI file - many remote applications

Tags: remote-desktop, msi, remoteapp

How can I create a single [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer file for many remote applications in [Remote Desktop Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) (RDS)?

Suppose I have 10 applications exposed via RDS. To make life easier I created MSI installer packages so users can "install" those applications. Currently I have 10 different MSI files which forces users to install 10 times. Is it possible to make all/some applications into a single MSI file?

(I don't control user machines so installing via [GPO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy_Object) or other magic is out of the question).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to chain multiple MSI packages so that they all install as one with Office 2003, so I'd guess that it's also generally possible with other apps.  There's a KB article on it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828947) which may give further useful info.

Failing that you could just provide a batch file that calls msiexec on the 10 different MSI packages.  Run msiexec /? for more info on the various command-line parameters available.

Comment: thank you for the hint about office 2003 thing. Unfortunately I'm afraid I will not be able to use it just like that since my .msi files are available via web page.

Answer (score 0):

MSI Files are just [databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can easily take the contents of one and inspect it.  If you were to look at the Remote App installs with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you would find a `File` table entry, some `Shortcut`s and a couple `Registry` entries if you have any associations.

If you were to take the records from each of those tables, add it to another MSI, or better yet [to a new MSI built with WiX](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/the-software-package), you could install an arbitrary number of remote applications at once.

MSI additionally [exposes an API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which would allow the [whole process to be scripted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556119/how-to-change-the-contents-of-a-file-included-in-an-msi-with-vbscript).